# Refresh page within an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, internet-explorer, refresh

I have an app (facebook canvas app, facebook displays the app in an iframe)

When the user clicks on a link I want to be able to refresh the page.

the code i m using to refresh the page is as follows:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

With firefox this works fine, it only refreshes the current page within the iframe. So i m happy.

With IE, the whole page is being refreshed which causes the user to go the beginning of the app.

How can i avoid that?

I just want refresh the current page not the current url.

```
apps.facebook.com/foo/
```

is the app URL and within URL user clicks on a link go to a page, then within that Page i need to refresh that page to update some counters. but when i refresh the whole request goes to `apps.facebook.com/foo/`

any ideas?

Comment: tried `document.location.reload(true);`?

Comment: same thing, refreshing the whole page

Comment: I've been using `location.reload` in iframes in IE just fine... What is `window` referring to, the content window of the iframe or the window containing the iframe?

Comment: I actually tried this window.location.href = "/home/browse"; and workeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in http://www.hyperorg.com/blogger/2007/03/24/refresh-an-iframe-in-ie-anyone/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function reload () {
    var fr=document.getElementById('tehframe');
    if(fr!=null) document.getElementById("wrapper").removeChild(fr);
    var iframehtml="<iframe id='tehframe' src=…></iframe>";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML=iframehtml;
}
```

Then just call `reload()` at the beginning and whenever you want to load it.

Comment: I actually tried this window.location.href = "/home/browse"; and workeed

Answer (score 7):

```
var oiframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');

oiframe.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use `window.location.href = window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url of the iframe and cause a refresh by adding a meaningless parameter to the url eg foo becomes foo?bar

Comment: I actually tried this `window.location.href = "/home/browse";` and workeed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick :

```
  <button onclick="window.parent.location = document.referrer">
    Reload
  </button>
```